# mongodb : limit the possible values of a number field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to limit the choices for a field in mongo:

```
units : { type: Number, default: 1 },
```

But I would like to add this constraint: something like

authorized values: [1, 10, 100, 1000]

Answer (score 8):

You are clearly using [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) for which there is an [enum](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_string_SchemaString-enum) type validator available:

```js
var mySchema = new Schema({
    "units": { "type": Number, "default": 1, "enum": [1,10,100,1000] }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no enum in MongoDB since there is no enum in json / bson, so yeah, you can't, you only can control entered values using your programming language (ex: fire an exception when an unexpected value is entered).

Comment: Not too hard to work out that the question is  actually about [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) based on the content. If you know it and understand it. Next time leave a comment when you are not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose's enum validator only works with string types, but you can use a [custom validator](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#customized) to do this:

```js
units : { 
    type: Number, 
    default: 1,
    validate: {
        validator: function (value) {
            return [1, 10, 100, 1000].indexOf(value) !== -1;
        },
        message: 'Value must be one of 1, 10, 100, 1000'
    }
}
```